# Should (or can) I submit my academic degrees while applying for permanent residence in the US?

Tags: usa, greencard

I am on a fiance visa in USA and I have married a US citizen.  Now I want to apply for permanent residence.

Since I hope to apply for a job in technical field later on in the US, should (or can) I submit my academic degrees to the USCIS while applying for the permanent residence? If not, how will my future employer verify my academics?

Answer (score 5):

Given that you will be applying for an adjustment of status based on your marriage to a US citizen and using form [I-485](http://www.uscis.gov/i-485) to do it you won't be providing it to USCIS.

There is generally no need for a US Government to check your educational credentials in this case and it's not a role of the US Government to confirm your educational credentials to your employer.

If such a verification is required it is normally done by your perspective employer and it uses organizations similar to [World Education Services](https://www.wes.org/) to evaluate your education and degree if they deem it necessary.